# What's the connection between "/etc/init.d" and "/etc/rcX.d" directories in Linux?

Tags: linux, init-script, sysvinit

I am learning command line from a book called "[Linux Command Line and Shell Scripting Bible, Second Edition](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1118004426)." The book states this:

> Some Linux implementations contain a table of processes to start
>   automatically on bootup. On Linux systems, this table is usually
>   located in the special file /etc/inittabs.
>
> Other systems (such as the popular Ubuntu Linux distribution) utilize
>   the /etc/init.d folder, which contains scripts for starting and
>   stopping individual applications at boot time. The scripts are started
>   via entries under the /etc/rcX.d folders, where X is a run level.

Probably because I am new to linux, I did not understand what the second paragraph quoted meant. Can someone explain the same in a much plainer language?

Comment: this has been asked many times [before](http://unix.stackexchange.com/search?q=rc.d+vs.+init.d)

Comment: @bdowning This one's different. I have a context. The questions I see in the page you linked to are different from this, IMO.

Comment: @bdowning off, but flag as duplicate would have been more informative if you feel so

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Let's forget `init.d` or `rcx.d` and keep things very simple. Imagine you were programming a program whose sole responsibility is to run or kill other scripts one by one.

However your next problem is to make sure they run in order. How would you perform that?

And lets imagine this program looked inside a `scripts` folder for running the scripts. To order the priority of scripts you would name them in lets say numerical order. This order is what dictates the relation between `init.d` and `rc`

In other words `init.d` contains the scripts to run and the `rcX.d` contains their order to run.

The `X` value in `rcX.d`  is the run level. This could be loosely translated to the OS current state.

If you dig inside the `rcX.d` scripts you will find this formatting:

```
Xxxabcd
```

- `X` is replaced with `K` or `S`, which stands for whether the script should be `killed` or `started` in the current run level
- `xx` is the order number
- `abcd` is the script name (the name is irrelevant however where it points is the script this will run)

Comment: wonderful explanation, very clear. Thanks @whoami

Answer (score 12):

There are several different init systems for Linux. The main ones are [SysVinit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Init#SysV-style) (the traditional one), [Upstart](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Upstart) (Ubuntu's replacement), and [SystemD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Systemd) (pushed by Fedora and Gnome). The directories `/etc/init.d` and `/etc/rc?.d` are used by SysVinit. The book may be mentioning them with regards to Ubuntu because the information is a bit dated (Ubuntu used to use SysVinit like everyone else) or because those directories still exist for compatibility.

`/etc/init.d` contains a bunch of scripts, each containing instructions to start and stop a service. Some of these services need to be started at boot time; others need to be started in multiuser mode but not in single-user maintenance mode; and it's possible to define different modes with different sets of desired services. SysVinit manages this through [runlevels](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Init#Runlevels). The directory `/etc/rc$N.d` contain the scripts to run when entering runlevel N (`/etc/rc$N.d/S*`) and the scripts to run when leaving runlevel N (`/etc/rc$N.d/K*`). Because many runlevels have scripts in common, rather than store a copy of the scripts for each runlevel, the scripts are all stored in a single location `/etc/init.d`, and the runlevel-specific directories `/etc/rc?.d` contain symbolic links. Furthermore the names of the symbolic links indicate whether the service is to be started (`S*`) or stopped (killed, `K*`) in that runlevel, and a numeric prefix is used to control the order in which the scripts are executed.

The script responsible for traversing `/etc/rc$N.d` is `/etc/init.d/rc` (on pre-Upstart Ubuntu and on Debian; locations may vary on other Linux distributions).

Comment: So, Ubuntu is not using `/etc/init.d` and `/etc/rc?.d` anymore, and has Upstart instead?

Comment: @KrishD'Souza Not quite. Ubuntu uses Upstart instead of SysVinit, but many packages still ship scripts in `/etc/init.d` (instead of Upstart `.conf` files in `/etc/init`), so Upstart still supports `/etc/init.d` and `/etc/rc?.d` for compatibility.

Comment: Ubuntu switched from Upstart to systemd since 15.04. So at this moment (16.04) Ubuntu has three init systems: SysVinit, Upstart and systemd. First and second are left for backward compatibility.

Answer (score 4):

`/etc/init.d` is the directory where the init scripts belong.

The `etc/rcX.d` is where links controlling which services are killed or started when entering runlevel `X`.  Files in `rcX.d` starting with K are executed with the parameter `stop`, and files starting with `S` are executed with the parameter `start`.  It is typical to sequence startup and stop order using a two digit number after the `K` or `S`.  To ensure proper start and stop ordering is it common for the two sequences to add up to 100.

Programs can be disabled in a run level by removing the links or changing the case of the `K` or `S` to `k` or `s`.

EDIT:  Administrators typically run the scripts from `/etc/init.d` which may be a symbolic link to another directory depending on distribution.  (Different distributions have different standards.)

The `rcX.d` are used by the initialization code to change run levels.

Comment: On most systems, `/etc/init.d` is a symlink to directory under `/etc/rc.d/init.d`

Comment: So, basically `/etc/init.d` is useless without `/etc/rcX.d`? And since `/etc/rcX.d` is the controller of programs that are launched at startup, it's function is similar to that of `/etc/init.d`, correct?

Comment: This depends on the system.  Gentoo, for example, uses only /etc/init.d for it's init files; it has no /etc/rc*.d directories.  Arch Linux, likewise, only has /etc/rc.d, instead of /etc/init.d.

Answer (score 1):

Although @BillThor has anwered it very well, here's my understanding of `/etc/rcX.d` and `/etc/init.d`:

- `/etc/init.d` contains scripts for starting and stopping individual applications at boot time.
- `/etc/rc?.d` directories represent various run levels and the scripts contained within are nothing but symbolic links to the actual scripts in `/etc/init.d` directory. Changing the run levels changes the mode of the system, like the very basic Single user mode to console-only mode to the advanced graphical interface.

So, there's no use of `/etc/rc?.d` directories without the `/etc/init.d` itself (and of course, vice-versa).